# How to not delete record when using AMQP in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus

I follow the sample in https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp10, but all records will be deleted by default when go through all messages by running the code. Is it any way and configuration that not delete the records after processing them.

The code I used is from [Polling an Azure Service Bus Queue from an Azure WebJob using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089590/polling-an-azure-service-bus-queue-from-an-azure-webjob-using-node-js/31207240)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution that use "receiverSettleMode:Constants.receiverSettleMode.settleOnDisposition", details in http://tips-tricksa.blogspot.com.au/2017/10/retrieve-records-from-azure-service-bus.html